# displaying the function of php

Tags: php

i have a php code here and wondering how can this display what you have wrote in the box: 
i did this and it did display this one: "$input"; ?>  "

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <form action="message.php" method="post">
 Enter your message: <input type="text" name="msg" size="30">
 <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

===============
this is my message.php

```
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>

     <?php
     // retrieve form data
     $input = $_POST['msg'];
      // use it
     echo "You said: <i>$input</i>";
     ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

=======

This is what i get as view page source:

```
        <html>
        <head></head>
         <body>

          <?php
           // retrieve form data
          $input = $_POST['msg'];
        // use it
         echo "You said: <i>$input</i>";
            ?>

            </body>
             </html>
```

Comment: do you have php enabled on your server?

Comment: Can you show us what you get when you view the generated source?

Comment: yes it is enabled. using xampp

Comment: Well... The code doesn't look faulty, there's a problem with something else.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger: which generated source now? the i created 2 phps. the form one is i.php and the 2nd one is message.php. which one then?

Comment: @tintincute: The one of message.php (what you get by right click and "show source code" in the browser)

Comment: when i called the i.php i got a box where i can type the message and the button send. after i click the send button i get this message: $input"; ?>

Comment: show us the soruce for message.php after you have submitted the form

Comment: @all: already edited my answer, the view page source please see above for updates

Comment: it's almost the same code of my message.php

Comment: Then PHP doesn't parse your document.

Comment: Did you request both pages via HTTP (e.g. `http://localhost/…`) and not via the filesystem?

Comment: ok guys, i found out that if i open the namedform.php with my notepad++ and have it run in my Firefox, it will open the page with the box where i can type something, and when i click on the "send" button it will give me an error. what's interesting is:if i call the url in my browser:http://localhost/namedform.php and click on send then it will display correctly. what seems to be the error here. does that mean i have to call it all the time in my browser?

Comment: yes. Otherwise, PHP won't find it. When opening from Notepad++, it just sends the local file to the browser, instead of going via the apache.

Comment: ok, hmm i am thinking how could php be helpful if you need to type it all the time. ok i think i'll continue to read the tutorials. now it's quite clear to me that i have to call it all the time, in the browser. thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view a html file from Notepad++, it will open in the browser from its location on the disk. Then the link in the form points to your php file on the disk. (The address field will read `file:///` and the php won't be parsed.)
Notepad++ doesn't know that the same file can be reached via http://localhost/namedform.htm so you'll have to access it via localhost in order to get the php parsing for message.php to work. Now your address field should start with `http://`. Later you can just hit "reload" in your browser after you made and !saved! any changes.

**edit:**
Although reloading php pages after edit & save seems to me like the natural thing even after years of php programming, here are some solutions that let you preview your file from notepad++ via the web server:

1. Add some javascript to the html file you want to preview that checks if the address starts with `http://` or `file:///`. If it is the latter, reload the file from `http://localhost`.
2. Search the settings of notepad++ for the default preview options. Change to preview from localhost. Maybe you need an extension for that. I'm not that deep into the subject.

Comment: ok is this some kind of problem of notepad++? i didn't try it yet with the text pad or so....

Comment: No, it's a feature of your operating system. If you preview from notepad++, it opens a file as if you would double click it in explorer. If you type an address with `http://localhost/...` in your browser, the apache server will be asked to send that file - thus being able to parse it. I'll edit my answer (again) to provide two solutions for you.

Comment: thanks for the input. so i need to change some settings in my notepad++ so that i don't need to type it all the time. I don't have background about java script but i think it will come later

Comment: I think you might consider getting used to [ctrl-s][alt-tab][ctrl-r] which translates to "save the file in notepad++" -> "change to browser window" -> "reload page". No typing needed there. Maybe some going forward and back in the browser, too ([alt-left] & [alt-right], btw).

Answer (score 7):

It's weird actually.Check once by typing only localhost on your web browser,then run you page with the correct path.If it shows your HTML page,then go for $_REQUEST in place of POST.Just add this on your message.php : -

```
<?php
print "<pre>";print_r($_POST);print "</pre>";
print "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);print "</pre>";
?>
```

Check what output you get after this...You can easily debug things like this.

Comment: i added the code and this is what i get: You said: test
Array
(
    [msg] => test
)

Array
(
    [msg] => test
    [SN4c73aca3275d4] => bs9jtbva1edr9inu5mqj6ivmt0
    [webfxtab_resourcesPane] => 0
    [webfxtab_settingsPane] => 4
    [webfxtab_childPane] => 0
)

Comment: i realized that i need to call the link all the time in the browser instead running it from notepad++... i just find it strange why...

Comment: yes you have to put the inside your server's root folder.Like if you are using apache as your server,you have to put the code in folder named htdocs

Answer (score 2):

The .php-file is not interpreted via your web-server (like Apache). You can not open the file in your browser via File->Open but you have to access it via a valid URL (like http://localhost/myphpfile.php).

Also check if the php interpreter module is enabled in your webserver.

Comment: i named the 1st code as : namedform.htm and the second code as: message.php

Comment: @heb: why i have to acces it via a valid URL? how does that work?

Comment: Which OS are you running? To develop web-apps with PHP you will need a local webserver (like Apache, Cherokee or IIS (on Windows)). The php file is only interpreted as a php source file if you open it via a web-server, else it will only open as a raw text or html file.

Comment: i'm using windows 7 and my webserver is xampp

Comment: Can you access http://localhost/ with your browser? If yes, can you access http://localhost/~YOURUSERNAME with your browser?

Comment: @heb:not really sure what's the username, when i installed the xampp i had "admin" as username. so if i type now localhost/~admin. it doesn't work, but i can access the localhost/myphpadmin

Comment: Using Linux I know there is a folder called public_html in your user home folder, which is mapped by apache to localhost/~USERNAME . I'm not sure if this is available in Windows but as XAMPP uses Apache as webserver there should be a module called "mod_userdir" which enabled this feature. I don't know how to load modules into apache with windows, but on linux there is a commandline tool called a2enmod (in your case call it with a2enmod userdir - which enables the userdir module), after a restart of apache the userdir function is available.

Comment: username is the name of your account, phpmyadmin is independent from this setting as it is defined as an extra location in the apache configuration.

Comment: As tintincute wrote in several comments to several answers, he's able to access the html and php in the browser via localhost, so apparently he uses the folder that apache gets the localhost content from... So imho no reason to confuse him with userdir. :)

Comment: It did work all the time, just not via the "preview" button of notepad++.

Comment: yes it work but i have to type it in the browser. thanks for the input though